# Sign In Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in. We received a bad request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

1. I am using azure AD authentication to authenticate a user in my MVC
   application.And I published my application on azure and it is
   working fine.
2. But, when I run my application locally then it Microsoft's login
   page comes up and when I enter credentials and click on SignIn
   button then it is giving "Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing
   you in.We received a bad request." 
   But the same application is on azure and if I access it from there then it    allow me to login.

---

To create this apllication I follwed [link to add azure AD authentication](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect)

[image]

Comment: Hold on, I'll just pop to the car and get my crystal ball... You haven't given even remotely enough information here. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You have a history of asking bad questions. I would suggest that you need to work on this or a [question ban may well be coming your way](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

Comment: When you get this error, usually you will see more details. One thing I have seen with this kind of error is that the user is not present in the Azure AD. Please share the detailed error message.

Comment: when I run my application locally then it Microsoft's login page comes up and when I enter credentials and click on SignIn button then it is giving "Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.We received a bad request." But the same application is on azure and if I access it from there then it allow me to login.

Comment: Put the details in the *question itself*. Also consider that it's VERY unlikely that Azure will allow login and redirection to an unknown development machine or external AD domain without at least *some* kind of configuration.

Comment: And please, please, PLEASE use proper formatting. It's impossible to read one continuous block of text

Comment: @Asha, I dont think this is that bad of a question, for someone who is hitting the same issue this is pretty much the same description I would give - MS just gives us no information. I would ask for the MS credential error code though in the bottom left of the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you notice the error message, it clearly indicates that you have not configured `https://localhost:44320` as one of the reply addresses.

Please go back to application configuration screen in your Azure AD and add `https://localhost:44320` as additional reply address. That should take care of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below to your `Web.config`. It must be the same port which you have added at the time of Application registration.

```
<add key="RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44320/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this, it has cost me a lot of time.

I would check firstly that you have the ability in Azure to access third party applications.

In Azure > Users & Groups > User Settings:

[image: Azure user settings]

You see the first item (Users can allow apps to access their data) - without this checked I believe it wont work.

As you are running your application locally it is not published to Azure, this means that although it may be within the realms of your organisations network, Azure still views it as a third party application.

Be wary setting this to 'Yes'. I understand that there are ways to then create applications that allow you to behave as an Azure super user....

Comment: Old question I know but I found nothing that addressed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this, here is what happened to me. I had been switching back and forth between environments within Visual Studio (Project >> Properties >> Debug >> Environment Variables). Well, the last time I switched it, I wrote "Develop" instead of "Development" to switch back. This caused .NET Core to grab the wrong appsettings which connected to the wrong AD which did not have my localhost setup on it. It took me an hour to catch what I had done wrong.

This may not be exactly what has happened to you, but do check to make sure you are picking up the Azure AD settings you are expecting if they are in your appsettings. It could be a good point to start at.